# defun completion and region

Tags: region, completing-read

Is it possible to write a function with completion that act on region?

A mix of:

```el
(defun function-style (style)
  (interactive
   (list
    (completing-read "Style: " styles-list)))
     ...
```

And

```el
(defun function-style (beg end)
      (interactive "r")
       ....
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The two functions take different arguments. What data are you going to work with in the function? What does “completion that act on region” mean: do you want to complete the content of the region, to use the region as default argument when called interactively, something else?

Comment: Please try to clarify the question, or it risks being closed as unclear.

Comment: I would like to write the function (defun my-function (beg end style) ....with completion for style

Comment: @djangoliv: I don't know what you mean by "completion for style".  This said, my crystal ball tells me you probably don't want to create a new command but just write a new function to add to `completion-at-point-functions`.

Comment: @stephan: As Tyler has understood, I wanted a solution for write the function my-function(beg end style) with list completion for style argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any elisp functions to generate the arguments for an `interactive` call. The code you use should return a list that matches the function arguments:

```el
(defun my-function (beg end style)
  (interactive
   (let ((string (completing-read "Style: " styles-list)))
     (list (region-beginning) (region-end) string)))
  <function body> )
```

See the the manual node [(elisp) Using Interactive](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_288.html) for details.